# How to list Google Merchant Center Feeds

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to read customers' feeds through Google API. I got an access token.

This is the documentation I followed: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/developers-guide-python#authentication

Example here shows an ACCOUNT_ID to use, but I don't understand where to receive this info.

```
import gdata.contentforshopping.client
ACCOUNT_ID = '1234567'
shopping_client = gdata.contentforshopping.client.ContentForShoppingClient(account_id=ACCOUNT_ID)
```

Here is what i did so far:

```
import gdata.contentforshopping.client
import gdata.gauth

part = 2

auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scope=SCOPE, user_agent=USER_AGENT)
shopping_client = gdata.contentforshopping.client.ContentForShoppingClient()
authorize_url = auth_token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri=APPLICATION_REDIRECT_URI)

if part == 1:
    print 'Please visit: %s' % authorize_url

elif part == 2:

    query = {'code': 'xxxx'} # received from result of part == 1
    auth_token.get_access_token(query)
    auth_token.authorize(shopping_client)
    accounts = shopping_client.GetClientAccounts()
    print(accounts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there is no proper way to do this. You have to get an error from old API and parse it to find out your merchant id.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-content-api-for-shopping/3iLEm9puJis